# Error when setting and getting values from my two dimensional array

Tags: c++

When I put a number in `flag[1][2]`, I will automatically put that same number in `flag[2][0]`.

Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void inicializarFlag(void);
void imrpimeflag(void);

int flag[2][2];

int main(){

    int i, j, escolha;

    inicializarFlag();
    cout<<"digite as posicoes e o valor: "<<endl;

    cin>>i;
    cin>>j;
    cin>>escolha;

    flag[i][j] = escolha;
    imrpimeflag();

    return 0;
}

void inicializarFlag(void){

    for (int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
            flag[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void imrpimeflag(void){

    for (int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: "<<flag[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize the array `int flag[2][2]`, you are initializing a 2x2 array, not a 3x3 array. Since arrays are zero indexed, `flag[2][0]` places an int in the zeroth column of the third row of the 2x2 flags array, which is out of bounds. The behavior of placing an element out of the bounds of an array is undefined, and can lead to problems like you describe.

Declare `int flag[3][3]` and the code should work.

Comment: Hi, i made the changes you said, but when i put a value in flag[2][0] it will put the same value in flag [1][3] now that ther is declared int flag[3][3], here is a print for the outcome...

http://imageshack.com/a/img633/5035/H7kYfp.jpg

Comment: Right - this is because if you declare `int flag[3][3]` then there are three rows and three columns, numbered 0, 1, and 2 for both the rows and the columns. In this case now, `flag[1][3]` is out of bounds because 3 marks not the third, but the fourth column of the 2D array (as arrays are indexed starting at 0). When you declare the array with `int flag[3][3]`, it means that you are declaring an array of size 3x3, but you can't use the number 3 to access any elements in the array because 3 marks the 4th column when you try to access elements - and you haven't declared that 4th column.

Comment: Just for correctness, the statement I made, "When you declare the array with int flag[3][3], it means that you are declaring an array of size 3x3", isn't exactly correct. But it serves its purpose for thinking about this problem.

Comment: Essentially, if you declare `int flag[3][3]`, then you can't do this in your for loop: `for (int i=0; i<=3; i++){` you have to do this: `for (int i=0; i<3; i++){` because the former will attempt to access the 4th element (at index 3) while the second will stop before that 4th element.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a rookie mistake hahah, i do understand it now! thxx for helping this poor soul husuhas!